# route issue when I host my laravel 5 website on a Shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel-5

hello everyone I'm new on laravel. I build my website which is perfectly working on the development machine but when I put it on my shared hosting it is just one route which is working ("/"). all the order routes are not working.

web.php (the first route is working)

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('index');}); 

Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}'], function(){
Route::get('index', function(){
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('t', function(){
    return view('construction');
});

Route::get('post', function(){
    return view('post');
});

Route::get('posts', 'postController@index');
});
```

my .htacces

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

index.blade.php is in the folder views of ressources and the lang files exist.
if anyone can help me it will be great

Comment: Is the hosting configured to send all requests to `public/index.php`?

Comment: I don't know where can I look that please?

Comment: You will have to contact your hosting company to ask this.

Comment: what error are u getting ?

Comment: error 404: not found!

Answer (score 0):

Here what you can do..

Step 1: Go to `public` folder, copy `.htaccess` file to root (`/`) directory

Step 2: Rename `server.php` to `index.php` in root folder

Step 3: Open `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helper.php`

Step 4: find code block

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
   return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
}
```

Replace it with

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
   return app('url')->asset('public/'.$path, $secure);
}
```

You are good to go.. :)

Comment: thanks for you proposition but I still have de same problem

Comment: please I have add my .htaccess. can you check if all is right?